# AngularJS - Hiding and Showing Element Without Use of JS/Script

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a set of headings (`<h3>`) that when clicked, they hide/show their corresponding sections.

I have achieved this by using `ng-show/ng-hide` and then calling a `$scope` variable isInactive/isActive.

What i would like to know, is if the same result can be achieved, without the need for using JS within `$scope.isInactive` and `$scope.isActive` and logic be placed in the HTML markup? Possibly with the us of `ng-class`?

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="EventController">
    <div class="tabs">
         <h3 class="" id="tab-{{$index}}-0"><a id="1" data="{{$index}}" ng-click="switch($event)">1 - 5 Years</a></h3>

         <h3 class="inactive" id="tab-{{$index}}-1"><a id="2" data="{{$index}}" ng-click="switch($event)">6 - 10 Years</a></h3>

         <h3 class="inactive" id="tab-{{$index}}-2"><a id="3" data="{{$index}}" ng-click="switch($event)">11 - 15 Years</a></h3>

         <h3 class="inactive" id="tab-{{$index}}-3"><a id="4" data="{{$index}}" ng-click="switch($event)">16 - 20 Years</a></h3>

        <div class="clear" data="{{$index}}" ng-hide="isInactive('#tab-'+{{$index}} + '-0')">1 - 5 Years Text - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</div>
        <br>
        <div class="clear" ng-show="isActive('#tab-'+{{$index}} + '-1')">6 - 10 Years Text - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</div>
        <br>
        <div class="clear" ng-show="isActive('#tab-'+{{$index}} + '-2')">11 - 15 Years Text - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</div>
        <br>
        <div class="clear" ng-show="isActive('#tab-'+{{$index}} + '-3')">16 - 20 Years Text - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function EventController($scope) {

$scope.
switch = function (e) {
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var elem = angular.element(target);
    var parent = elem.parent();
    var allHeadings = parent.parent().find("h3");

    angular.forEach(allHeadings, function (aHeading) {
        var child = angular.element(aHeading);
        child.addClass("inactive");
    });
    parent.removeClass("inactive");
}

$scope.isInactive = function (e) {
    var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector(e));
    if (elem.hasClass("inactive")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

$scope.isActive = function (e) {
    var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector(e));
    if (elem.hasClass("inactive")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};

}
```

My jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/Wr79J/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have correctly identified this the apt place for using `ng-class`.

It is possible to do only using HTML and a minimalistic controller: http://jsfiddle.net/Wr79J/4/

**JS**

```js
function EventController($scope) {
    $scope._activeTab = 1;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div ng-app="">
    <div ng-controller="EventController">
        <div class="tabs">
             <h3 ng-class="{ 'inactive': _activeTab !== 1, 'active': _activeTab == 1 }">
               <a id="1" ng-click="_activeTab=1">1 - 5 Years</a></h3>

     <!-- .... -->

    <div class="clear" ng-show="_activeTab == 1">
       1 - 5 Years Text - Lorem ipsum ...
    </div>

</div>
```

**Note:** I think you were using `{{$index}}` from a scope this part of the template had inherited. I have left that untouched in the example.

Though this works, this code is not very maintainable. You may want to use more descriptive names for the tabs instead of `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`.

You can get rid of the controller completely using an [`ng-init="_activeTabe = 1"`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) on the container div, but it is not the correct use of `ng-init`.

---

Also, it is not considered good practise to manipulate the DOM in *any way* from the controller (I am looking at the `addClass/removeClass` in the code). If it is necessary, then one should use *directives* (e.g. `ng-class`) for the manipulation.

Comment: thanks for the detailed solution, what do you think to guru's solution with no JS at all?

Comment: @OamPsy He is using the `ng-init` trick which is not condoned in the docs. I have mentioned it in my answer after the **Note**.

Comment: Thanks for outlining this

Comment: I dont understand how the .inactive CSS class is being applied. How would it work if the CSS class was called .tabs-inactive for example?

Comment: @OamPsy `ng-class="{ 'tabs-inactive' : _activeTab !== 1, ...}"`. There [are several ways of using `ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and I am using the one in which the keys of the Object passed are the class names which are applied to the element if the value is _truthy_. You can add quote marks around the class names. I didn't add the quotation marks around the class names `active` and `inactive` out of laziness. Updated the answer.

Comment: @musically_uat - Thanks, however i cant see your updated version with " You can add quote marks around the class names"

Comment: @OamPsy I have used single quotes to prevent interference with the double quotes used for the attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set a variable to set the active tab.

```
<div class="tabs">
  <h3 ng-click="range=1">1-5</h3>
  <h3 ng-click="range=2">6-10</h3>
  <div class="clear" ng-show="range==1">1 - 5 Years Text</div>
  <div class="clear" ng-show="range==2">6 - 10 Years Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example - http://plnkr.co/edit/NTVPbOC5k7HKo88qp6vN?p=preview with no javascript code for the above logic.

```
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="tabs">
        <h3 ng-init="active=1" ng-click="active=1" ng-class="{true:'active', false:'inactive'}[active==1]"><a >1 - 5 Years</a></h3>
        <h3 ng-click="active=2" ng-class="{true:'active', false:'inactive'}[active==2]"><a >6 - 10 Years</a></h3>
        <h3 ng-click="active=3" ng-class="{true:'active', false:'inactive'}[active==3]"><a >11 - 15 Years</a></h3>
        <h3 ng-click="active=4" ng-class="{true:'active', false:'inactive'}[active==4]"><a >16 - 20 Years</a></h3>

        <div ng-show="active==1">1 - 5 Years Text - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</div>
        <br>
        <div ng-show="active==2">6 - 10 Years Text - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</div>
        <br>
        <div ng-show="active==3">11 - 15 Years Text - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</div>
        <br>
        <div ng-show="active==4">16 - 20 Years Text - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```